# "Please specify shipping method" - Paypal express/free shipping

Tags: magento2, shipping, shipping-methods, paypal-express, delivery

First of all I have very limited knowledge of magento so please excuse any stupid questions I might be asking.

I have a magento website built for me, only using paypal express checkout and up until recently I've had no issues. I offer 2 shipping methods - a flat rate of £2.99 for orders under £25 and free delivery for orders of £25 or more.

Since Monday any customer placing an order of £25+ and selecting the free shipping option is experiencing problems. They are completing the payment process with paypal however the transaction is failing and they are then being redirected back to my site with an error message "please specify shipping method". Alongside this message is a drop down box to select a shipping method, however it only provides customers with the option of £2.99 shipping, not the free delivery they initially selected and qualify for.

I've never had this issue before and customers placing orders of less than £25 and selecting the paid for delivery option are not having any issues.

Any advice on what might be causing this and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: best is to check the server logs

Comment: Check in Magento paypal method advanced settings, which have option "Transfer Shipping Options" to "Yes". May be you have set default to "no" in admin.